# OpenCV and color levels

Tags: opencv, image-processing, photoshop, levels

I have two pictures. The original and another with the color levels modified with Photoshop. [This box](http://cdn.cambridgeincolour.com/images/tutorials/levels_psex1.png)

I need to extract the amount of dark, white and mid in the input levels applied to the original image that result in the modified one. I try comparing some of the pixels. I get good approximations sometimes.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I only need this 3 parameters

Comment: take pixel pairs from source and altered image, then throw that data into a regression. you'd want to apply something more complex than a linear/affine function to this. you should figure out what kind of function photoshop applies there. it might be a gamma correction, or not. -- [mre] implies that you provide input data. please do so.